# I couldn't insert data to firestore on flutter

Tags: flutter

I couldn't insert the duration in firestore on flutter. In 'field6'. type of data from firestore should match with field6 .How to do that?

'field5' inserting correctly
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJWo7.png)

CODE

duration calculating method

```
DateDuration? duration;

  void calAge() {
    DateTime? birthday = selectedDate;

    duration = AgeCalculator.age(birthday!);
    print('Your age is $duration');
  }
```

inset firestore

```
void send() {
       FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("data").doc().set({
      "field5": selectedDate,
      "field6": Duration(duration).toString(),
    });
  }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEwpm.png)

Answer (score 0):

Saving dates in firestore can be tricky if you need to save the current datetime you need to use **FieldValue.serverTimestamp()** provided by firebase but if you need to be more dynamic, you can save it as a string then when getting it back from firestore you will use **DateTime.parse(your string date)** also you can save it as an int and when getting it you use **DateTime.fromMicrosecondsSinceEpoch(your int date)** if your time stamp is in micro seconds but use this if its in seconds  **DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(your int date)**